# Calling custom hook inside custom React Router v5 route causes maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

this is my first post on StackOverflow and I'll appreciate everyone's time trying to help with the issue I'm having.

**Stack:** React 17.0.1, React Router Dom 5.2.0, Redux 4.0.5

**Intended behaviour:** Custom route component should check timestamp property of the auth object in redux state and verify (using custom hook) whether it is 20 min old or younger. If check passes, route displays requested content, otherwise redirects user to login page.

**Actual behaviour**: maximum update depth exceeded error immediately after the app is launched

**What I tried**:

- I changed the custom hook to just return false and then true to make sure this isn't caused by incorrect hook behaviour. Still gotten the error for both false and true return values.
- using just the result of timestamp verification as the only condition for route's ternary operator inside render prop. Still getting the error.
- replacing variable (authTimestampValid) that stores result of calling custom hook in ternary operator inside render prop function with: true - *no error*, false - error

**Conclusion**: The things I've tried lead me to believe I created an infinite loop of custom hook calls
inside the custom route component, but I don't understand how. This actually might not be the case since I'm still getting the error when replacing authTimestampValid with false.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector((state) => state.auth)
  const assetsLoaded = useSelector((state) => state.loading.status === 'FETCHED')
  const fetchError = useSelector((state) => state.loading)
  const { valid: authTimestampValid } = useVerifyTimestamp()

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) => (
        isAuthenticated.uid && authTimestampValid
        ? (
            <>
              <Navigation />
              {assetsLoaded
                ? children
                : fetchError.status === 'FETCH_ERR'
                  ? <p>{fetchError.error}</p>
                  : <Spinner />
              }
            </>
          ) 
        : (
            <Redirect to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: location }
            }}/>
          )
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: you are calling validTimestamp and hitting in render method thats why its giving update depth exceed error, call it before render method

Comment: Can you explain Ayushi? I’m calling useVerifyTimestamp hook in the body of component and destructuring it into the authTimestampValid variable, which is then used in the render method